# returning component inside function not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, return, components

I've a component which i'm rendering by considering some conditions. It's done as follows

```
const Test = () => {
    return <div className="text_align_center white_color">
        <span><i className="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            No internet connection. Please check your connection settings and try again
        </span>
    </div>
}

function checkInternetConnection(){

    isOnline().then(online => {

       if(online === true){

           console.log("Came in here")

            return <Test/>

        }

    });
}
```

Then i'm calling my function as follows

```
const App = () => (
    <div className="ui container">

        {checkInternetConnection()}
);
```

But the issue is eventhough i'm getting the console log inside `checkInternetConnection` function, the returned component is not appearing. What can be cause of this?

Comment: `checkInternetConnection` function is returning `undefined`.Also you should not return a component like this from any async function.

Comment: Your `checkInternetConnection` function does not return anything. Perhaps you meant to return the promise? Note that the return function of the callback passed to `.then` will _not_ be returned out of the function creating the promise. Your question might be more about how promises work than anything.

Comment: @CraZy use state variable, and update the state inside promise, use that state variable to render the component [Conditional Rendering].

Comment: @MayankShukla i thought of that. But the problem is this is not a class file. From my understanding i can only create states in classes right?

Comment: @CraZyDroiD yes, you need to convert that Stateless Functional Component into Stateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `<Test/>` is being returned by the `then` callback function, not your `checkInternetConnection` function. Because you are conditionally rendering based on some asynchronous operation, you need to take a different approach in order for your component to update correctly.

One idea is to turn your stateless component into a **stateful** component by making it a class, and calling **setState** when your promise resolves:

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isOnline: false // set initial state to false 
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        isOnline().then(online => {
            this.setState({
                isOnline: true; // call setState to update state and rerender App
            });
        });
    }

    render() { // use inline expression to conditionally show <Test/> if isOnline is true

        return (

            <div className="ui container">

              { this.state.isOnline && <Test /> }

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `isOnline()` has a `.then()` clause I assume it is an asynchronous Promise?

If that is the case, then that is your culprit. The component will not re-render when the promise returns as React only renders when state changes, which is not the case here.

To get the behavior you describe do the rendering of the Test component based on a state variable and set it in your `.then()` when the promise returns.